# Finding infinitely many Myhill–Nerode equivalence classes

Tags: finite-automata

I need to prove the following languages are not regular and I'm having a
tough time identifying the equivalence class that can have an infinite
index.

How would I go about doing these? I know how to prove it after finding
the equivalence class but any tips on how to identify the one that has
the infinite index?

I know I should find the equivalence class where there are distinct
extensions for each string belonging to $L$, but could anyone help me
out on these 2:

1. $0^m  1^n$ where $m$ is even or $m$ is greater than $n$
2. $0^m  1^n$ where $\text{gcd}(m,n)=1$.

Comment: For (1) look at the strings $0^{2n+1}1$, for $n=1,2,3,...$. Observe that each must belong to different classes. In fact, if $m>n\geq 2$, then $x=0^{2m+1}1$ and $y=0^{2n+1}1$ can be distinguished by appending the string $z=1^{2n}$, since $xz=0^{2m+1}1^{2n}\in L$ and $yz=0^{2n+1}1^{2n+1}\not\in L$.

Comment: For (2) you can look at the classes of $0^p1^{p-1}$, with $p$ prime. Observe that $x=0^p1^{p-1}$ and $y=0^q1^{q-1}$, with $p\neq q$ primes,  can be distinguished by appending $z=1^{q+1}$. We get that $xz=0^{p}1^{p+q}\in L$ and $yz=0^{q}1^{2q}\not\in L$.

Comment: for part 2 how do we explain that the gcd(p,p+q)=1. I know it is true but there is no formal definition or theorem that shows it's true.

Comment: If $d=\gcd(p,p+q)$, then, in particular, $d$ divides $p$. Since $p$ is prime, we must have either $d=1$ or $d=p$. In the first case we got the desired answer. Let's look at the second case $d=p$. If $d=p$, then we must have that $p$ divides $p+q$. It follows that $p$ must divide $q$. Since $q$ is prime, we must have that $p=q$. But we had assumed that $p\neq q$. Thererfore, this case $d=p$ cannot happen.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider your second example (the first example is easier). We will be interested in
$$
F(m) = \{ n : 0^m 1^n \in L \} = \{ n : \gcd(m,n) = 1 \}.
$$
If $F(m_1) \neq F(m_2)$, then $m_1$ and $m_2$ belong to two different equivalence classes.

From $F(m)$ you can recover the set of primes dividing $m$: $p \in F(m)$ iff $p \not\mid m$. In particular, this shows that if $p_1 \neq p_2$ are two different primes, then $F(p_1) \neq F(p_2)$. Since there are infinitely many primes, we conclude that there are infinitely many different equivalence classes.

The first example can be analyzed in a similar way (considering only odd $m$).